# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {DB797690-40E0-11D2-9BD5-0060082AE372} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: vb.net, dll, clsid

While migrating .net application to 64 bit Windows 10 the above runtime error is occuring.I tried all the possible ways but still not working.Also the above mentioned key is not there in the clsid of registry. How to tackle it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svvl2.png)
and when I tried to register the dll I got this dialog box.

Comment: *"I tried all the possible ways"* - and which ones are these?

Comment: I mean, you can try to find in the registry, to which component this class id is belonging

Comment: If it's not in the registry, then presumably a required registration step has not been completed.

Comment: How to register the Clsid in the registry? As I checked in the registry this file is not available HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DB797690-40E0-11D2-9BD5-0060082AE372}.. Kindly let me know how to register it.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the referenced com file in the registry.

ex)

1. cmd
2. regsvr32 c:\test\test.dll

If the file you are referencing is made of .net
Find the 'RegAsm.exe' file and try to register.

ex2)

cd C:\test

RegAsm test.dll /unregister

RegAsm test.dll /codebase

or If your project has a 64-bit build, try building it with a 32-bit change.

Comment: Tried registering but it displayed that the entrypoint dll-RegisterServer was not found

Comment: If the file you are referencing is made of .net
Find the 'RegAsm.exe' file and try to register.
ex)
`cd C:\test

RegAsm test.dll /unregister

RegAsm test.dll /codebase`